# Determine the nature of parameter in runtime

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator

I have a function

```
void fname(char* Ptr)
{
    ...
}
```

I want to know inside this function whether this pointer `Ptr` holds the address of dynamically allocated memory using `new char[]` or the address of locally allocated memory in the calling function. Is there any way I can determine that? I think `<typeinfo>` doesn't help here.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have your own `operator new` functions and keep track of everything allocated so that you can just ask your allocation library if the address given is one it allocated. The custom allocator then just calls the standard one to actually do the allocation.

Another approach (messy and details highly OS dependent) may be to examine the process layout in virtual memory and hence determine which addresses refer to which areas of memory.

You can combine these ideas by actually managing your own memory pools. So if you get a single large chunk of system memory with known address bounds and use that for all `new`'d memory, you can just check that an address in is the given range to answer your question.

However: Any of these ideas is a lot of work and not appropriate if this problem is the only purpose in doing so.

Having said all that, if you do want to implement something, you will need to work carefully through all the ways that an address might be generated.

For example (and surely I've missed some):

- Stack
- Return from new
- Inside something returned from new.
- Was returned from new but already deleted (hopefully not, but that's why we need diagnostics)
- statically allocated
- static constant memory
- command line arguments/ environment
- code addresses.

Now, ignoring all that for a moment, and assuming this is for some debug purpose rather than system design, you might be able to try this kind of thing:

**This is ugly, unreliable, not guaranteed by the standard, etc etc**, but might work . . .

```
char* firstStack  = 0;

bool isOnStack(const void* p)
{
    char* check =(char*)p;
    char * here = (char*)&check;
    int a = firstStack - check;
    int b = check - here;
    return (a*b > 0);
}

void g(const char* p)
{
    bool onStack = isOnStack(p);
    std::cout << p  << (onStack ? "" : " not" ) << " on stack " << std::endl;
}

void f()
{
    char stuff[1024] = "Hello";
    g(stuff);
}

void h()
{
    char* nonsense = new char[1024];
    strcpy(nonsense, "World");
    g(nonsense);
    delete [] nonsense;
}

int main()
{
    int var = 0;
    firstStack = (char*)&var;
    f();
    h();    
}
```

Output:

> Hello on stack
>
> World not on stack

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: no, you can't. You have no way of knowing whether `Ptr` is a pointer to a single `char`, the start of a statically allocated array, a pointer to a single dynamically allocated `char`, or the start of an array thereof.

If you really wanted to, you try an overload like so:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void fname(char Ptr[N])
{
   // ...
}
```

which would match when passed a statically allocated array, whereas the first version would be picked when dealing with dynamically allocated memory or a pointer to a single `char`.

(But note that function overloading rules are a bit complicated in the presence of templates -- in particular, a non-template function is preferred if it matches. So you might need to make the original function take a "dummy" template parameter if you go for this approach.)

Comment: One possibility I see is through use of `delete[]` operator. If the pointer doesn't hold the address of dynamically allocated memory then `delete[] Ptr`should create runtime error. Any advantages of it here?

Comment: @Prakash No, `delete[]` doesn't throw an exception (in C++11, it's explicitly marked `noexcept`). Attempting to use it on something statically allocated is at best undefined behaviour, and will probably just crash.

Answer (score 0):

In vc++ there is an assertion _CrtIsMemoryBlock (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww5t02fa.aspx#BKMK_CRT_assertions) that can be used to check if a pointer was allocated from the heap. This will only work when a debug heap is being used but this is fine if you are just wanting to add some 'debug only' assertions. This method has worked well for me in the past under Windows.

For Linux however I know of no such equivalent.

Alternatively you could use an inline assembler block to try to determine the if it is a stack address or not. This would be hardware dependent as it would rely heavily not only on the processor type but also on the memory model being used (flat address model vs segmented etc). Its probably best to avoid this type of approach.